# I want to graph a heatmap for three parameter data

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, graphics, data, fractals

I want to plot a heatmap where $x$ varies from $0.1$ to $1$, $y$ varies $0.1$ to $1$, and a third parameter representing image generation times for different $(x,y)$ will be the input to a `ColorFunction`.

Comment: We need more information. Do you have a dataset you could share as an example? What have you tried so far? Have you seen [`ArrayPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPlot.html) or [`ListDensityPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html)?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. To get a focused response, you must post a well-formed and a well-articulated question along with copy-paste-able Mathematica code that you have tried. It is also a good idea to stay responsive to comments. Since you have not provided additional details as requested, the most likely outcome for this post will be a closure when a sufficient number of close votes have been cast. Thanks.

Comment: For example: x varies from 0 to 1, y form 0 to 1 and time varies from 11 to 22 sec. I want to choose time as a colorfunction or heatmap while x and y are coordinates in 2d.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example which may meet your needs:

```
x = Range[.1, 1, .1];

y = Range[.1, 1, .1];

heatMapInput[a_, b_] := Cos[Pi*a] + Sin[Pi*.25*b]

heatMapInput[x, y];

heatMap = 
  MapThread[Append, {Partition[Riffle[x, y], 2], heatMapInput[x, y]}];

ListDensityPlot[heatMap, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

> [image: Toy Example]